# CEF or CefSharp always renders the first instance of an <object> tag

Tags: html, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

We are having issues with the `<object>` tag in chromium.

In our web application we are pushing base64 content into the tag, and it renders the content as expected when using Chrome, but it's when we do this in cef/cefsharp that the issues happen. The object only renders the first document selected. Any subsequent selections still renders the initial object. I can see the data tag being updated to new content, and the object appears to load, but it always loads the first document selected.

If we replace the tag's `outerHTML` with a new object tag with the new content, the data displays correct, but this is not really an option because the web application works as expected in Chrome.

We have a web application that is also required to run embedded inside a bespoke application, and for this we are using CefSharp. We are currently on version 49.0.1 and can unfortunately not upgrade to the latest version because the client's machines do not have the latest version of the .NET framework installed yet.

Comment: That version isn't supposed anymore, of you cannot upgrade then consider switching to CefGlue or ChromiumFx.

Comment: Thanks, but none of these are an option. I have found a work-around. Will post the answer

Comment: Long as your aware there is no support for older versions.

Comment: Yes, we are. We're trying to push the client to get the .NET versions upgraded but for now the hack will have to do. We are running out of support on other libraries as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is (was) an issue with chromium (see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=567329)).

What we had to do to solve the problem was set the `<div>` that holds the `<object>`'s display to 'none', set the data, and then set the display back to 'block'. Probably just a rendering issue. Crisis averted.